# Добавить К столбцов в начало матрицы

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку. Создается сначала матрица размером raws*cols, заполненная случайными значениями. Далее пользователь вводит количество столбцов, которые нужно добавить в начало матрицы. Их тоже нужно заполнить случайными значениями. Я расширил память, отведенную на каждый ряд матрицы, до cols + K элементов с помощью функции realloc. Потом пытаюсь сдвинуть все существующие столбцы в конец матрицы и добавить в начало К столбцов. Но они не сдвигаются, в последних столбцах(которые добавились), остается мусор, а добавленные столбцы перекрывают существующие. Помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int raws, cols;
int **array;
int i, j, K;
puts("Enter the amount of raws in array(positive integer)");
scanf_s("%d", &raws);
puts("Enter the amount of columns in array(positive integer)");
scanf_s("%d", &cols);
if ((array = (int**)calloc(raws, sizeof(int*))) == 0) {
    puts("Memory allocation failure **array");
    exit(1);
}

for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    if ((array[i] = (int*)calloc(cols, sizeof(int))) == 0) {
        puts("Memory allocation failure *array");
        exit(1);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        array[i][j] = rand() % (raws*cols);
        printf("%8d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

puts("Enter the amount of cols to add to the beginning of array(positive integer)");
scanf_s("%d", &K);
for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    if ((array[i] = (int*)realloc(array[i], (cols + K) * sizeof(int))) == 0) {
        puts("Memory allocation failure after expanding for *array");
        exit(1);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    for (j = cols + K - 1; j <= K; j--) {
        array[i][j] = array[i][j - K];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < K; j++) {
        array[i][j] = rand() % (raws*cols);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < raws; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols + K; j++) {
        printf("%8d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: По хорошему, нужно в новом месте память выделять под всю матрицу и заполнять её из старой.

Comment: нужно именно добавить столбцы в уже существующую матрицу

Comment: Ну, realloc() ведь и не добавляет столбцы в существующую, он, вроде как, выделяет новый кусок и переносит туда старые данные. Кто мешает сделать эту же работу ручками? И еще, я бы предложил использовать не поэлементное копирование элементов, а использовать memmove() - она позволяет передвигать содержимое если источник и целевой блок пересекаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в цикле, точнее в условии выхода:

> for (j = cols + K - 1; j <= K; j--) {

Должно быть:

> for (j = cols + K - 1; j >= K; j--) {

---

*Не забудьте освободить выделенную память*

Comment: такая мелочь... Спасибо большое